# converting the values in a text file and making new text file in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, file

I have a text file like this example:

example:

```
"class" "Name"  "Access"    "CF33456_12.RCC"    "CF33457_05.RCC"    "CF33458_04.RCC"
"ff"    "edi"   "ff"    "kju"   2444.91910958478    1669.55827263364    699.627215729572
"gg"    "edi"   "gg"    "uhy"   2002.95278984564    369.565070720533    351.056685823175
```

in this file there are 6 columns (based on the headers) ,so the 1st column is rows name. I would like to change the numbers (the last 3 columns) to log2 value and make a new file with exactly similar structure. here is the expected output:

expected output:

```
"class" "Name"  "Access"    "CF33456_12.RCC"    "CF33457_05.RCC"    "CF33458_04.RCC"
"ff"    "edi"   "ff"    "kju"   11.2555710189065    10.7052507333626    9.45044260143907
"gg"    "edi"   "gg"    "uhy"   10.9679127014901    8.52968459728736    8.45556019395986
```

I am tryint to do that in python using this code:

```
df = pd.read_table("myfile.txt", index_col=0)
import numpy as np
df2 = df.iloc[:, [3,4,5]]
df3 = np.array(df2)
df4 = np.log2(df3)
final = pd4.DataFrame(df4)
```

it convert to `log2` value but it does not return a file with the same structure. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: What is the difference between the expected and actual structure?

Comment: Could you edit your code to make it fully runable?

Comment: @brandon: the only difference is the values of the last 3 columns. structure is the same. the code is runable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example the original dataframe (which has the structure of the input table) can be changed using this code:

```
    df = pd.read_table("myfile.txt", index_col=0)
    import numpy as np
    df2 = df.iloc[:, [3:5]]
    df3 = np.array(df2)
    df4 = np.log2(df3)
    df.iloc[:, [3:5]] = df4
    final = df
```

(it is obvious that `df4` has another format - it is a slice of the table and the indexes are removed while converting to numpy array)